# CASE WHEN not working in T-SQL (SSMS) Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, ssms

I'm using SSMS (T-SQL) to find even numbers in the `ID` column. My code does not recognize the `CASE WHEN column AS 'Nums'`. What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
SELECT 
    City, ID,
    (CASE
        WHEN ID % 2 = 1 THEN 'Odd'
        ELSE 'Even'
     END) AS Nums
FROM 
    STATION
WHERE 
    Nums = 'Even'
```

The error I get:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server dbrank-tsql, Line 6
> Invalid column name 'Nums'

Comment: You would have to do the case statement in the where clause as well or do a sub select.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference a newly introduced "computed" column in the `WHERE` clause - you'd have to e.g. use a CTE (or a subquery) to achieve this:

```
WITH DataCte AS
(  
    SELECT 
        City, ID,
        CASE
            WHEN ID % 2 = 1  
                THEN 'Odd'
                ELSE 'Even'
        END AS Nums
    FROM 
        STATION
)
SELECT City, ID, Nums
FROM DataCte
WHERE Nums = 'Even';
```

Answer (score 1):

This because you can not used 'Nums' for comparing because 'Nums' is not a column it is only **alias**, try following

```
Select City,ID,
(CASE WHEN ID % 2 = 1 THEN 'Odd' ELSE 'Even' END) AS Nums
From STATION
Where ID % 2 = 0
```

if you want to used 'Nums' as column than used with as a following

```
With T As
(Select City,ID,
(CASE WHEN ID % 2 = 1 THEN 'Odd' ELSE 'Even' END) AS Nums
From STATION)
Select * From T Where Nums = 'Even'
```

Comment: `Nums` is most definitely a column of the result set. An alias is when an existing column is given a new name. The reason it can't be used is only because `WHERE` logically happens before `SELECT`, so `Nums` is not in scope.